# Is this correct for a Chi2 test in r?

Tags: r, chi-squared

```
df18 <-data.frame(Level=c("East", "North", "South", "West"),
                 Mean=c(1,2,3,4),
                 Max=c(5,6,7,8),
                 Min=c(9,10,11,12))

chisq.test(df18$Bank, df18$Mean, correct=FALSE)
chisq.test(df18$Bank, df18$Max, correct=FALSE)
chisq.test(df18$Bank, df18$Min, correct=FALSE)
```

Am I right to test each variable like this? New to r and stats so have got myself a bit confused (data substituted here)

I did the tests and it came out ok but now second guessing myself!

Comment: What are your hypotheses? A statistical test should generally only be performed if you have an underlying hypothesis and null hypothesis you want to test.

Comment: Hi Yeah its if mean/max/min temperature differs across levels, null = no difference